# Indexing an Entity

Tags: c#, indexing, entity

In my silverlight project I have many views that all need the same method, "Tester()". Obviously I want this method to be resusable but I am just not getting there.

**What I have is this:**

```
    void Tester(IList<MyEntity> list)
    {
        var sortedlist=list.OrderBy(me=>me.Sortkey).ToList();
    }
```

This works fine, but only for MyEntity.

**What I really want is essentially this:**

```
 void Tester<T>(IList<T> list, string mySortField)
    {
        var sortedlist=list.OrderBy("mySortField").ToList();
    }
```

Doesn't compile.

Any ideas how to do this, please ? 
Thx in advance, Frank

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505

Comment: @Haris that should be an answer.  If you don't do that I will :)

Comment: @user24601 go ahead I am too lazy to do it ;)

Comment: Thanks Haris, that link sure seems helpful.

Comment: As suggested by Haris I ended up using DynamicQueryable which worked just fine. BTW: Had to comment out all references to ReadWriterLock as it isn't supported in SL 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
void Tester<T>(IList<T> list, Func<T, object> mySort) {
    var sortedlist=list.OrderBy(mySort).ToList();
}
...
Tester<MyEntity>(list, t => t.mySortField);
```

Although it's a little more verbose than passing a string, at least you get compile-time checking of sort fields.